# Can't seem to download a CSV using PHP Curl when response is content-disposition:attachment

Tags: php, http, curl

I am trying to download a CSV file from a URL using PHP Curl, but the Curl response is the HTML of the page, and not the CSV. How do I fix this?

I've tried matching the referer and user-agent.

Thanks!

Here is a working request in firefox:

```
GET [someURL] HTTP/1.1
Host: [someHost]
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: [someReferer]
Cookie: [some cookie data, including jsession]
```

and here's the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/csv
Date: Sun, 05 Jun 2011 00:33:21 GMT
Expires: Sun, 05 Jun 2011 00:34:21 GMT
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=[some file name.csv]
Connection: Keep-Alive
Last-Modified: Sun, 05 Jun 2011 00:33:21 GMT
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
Content-Length: 5012
```

Comment: the URL you're connecting to is a secret?

Comment: please add the curl source code or commandline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that option that you are looking for is ***-J***:

From http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-J:

> -J, --remote-header-name
>
> (HTTP) This option tells the -O, --remote-name option to use the
>   server-specified Content-Disposition filename instead of extracting a
>   filename from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `curl -L -O http://example.com/filename.csv`

That's a capital o, not a zero. This tells curl to follow any redirects and use the filename from the `content-disposition` header.